# Can ActiveRecord use specific geometric "path" type from postgres?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Greetings to everyone!
As I found [in documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition/column) ActiveRecord shall support non-native types.
I tried create a new "Route" model and then migrate, but I got this:

```
$ rails g model Route note:text route:path
...
$ rake db:migrate
undefined method `path' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::TableDefinition
...
```

Maybe I missed something?

PostgresQL - 9.2.4, gem 'pg' - 0.15.0

Please forgive me for my weird english.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord only supports the common native types for generated migrations.  These types are hardcoded as:

```
%w( string text integer float decimal datetime timestamp time date binary boolean)
```

It also supports a few 'virtual' helper types: `timestamps` and `references`

You can, however, generate the column as something else (say, integer) and then modify the generated code to look like this:

```
create_table :routes do |t|
  t.text :note
  t.column :route, :path
end
```

Comment: I was confused by that "polygon type in MySQL" exaple in AR docs.  
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#geometric-types), it is now available.

> All geometric types, with the exception of points are mapped to normal text. A point is casted to an array containing x and y coordinates.

I can confirm that I was able to create a model with a path type. The path is converted to a string in Rails but saved as a path in your PostgreSQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Since **Rails 5** you can use [specific geometric data type](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/3991ebcb36ac6694b35a3d3ab79a6b9c1e48bed1) commands when you run your migrations, so now you can use

`t.path :coordinates`

instead of

`t.column :coordinates, :path`

- assuming you are inside of your **create_table** block

You can see all the available options in the [PostgreSQL adapter](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb) file.

Find more details about [Geometric Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-geometric.html) (point, line, lseg, box, path, polygon, circle) and [Geometric Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-geometry.html) (intersects?, contains?, distance between, etc) in official PostgreSQL docs (currently in version 10.5).

If you need more powerfull functions and proccesing over spatial data, try the [Active Record PostGIS adapter](https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter) gem.